# Tem como alterar a ordem vertical de divs por CSS?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho o seguinte layout de uma página gerada automaticamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de trazer a *Fonte*, para junto da *Data* (logo abaixo). Mas eu não posso mudar disposição dos elementos gerados. Só posso alterar um template com os elementos HTML externos, uma div por fora de todo esse conteúdo, CSS. Essa página será enviada por email como um *Newsletter*, então acredito que Javascript não seria uma boa ideia.

Tem como fazer isso somente com CSS?

[ver no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andretf/e54eZ/)

Comment: André, é isto que quer? __http://jsfiddle.net/e54eZ/1/__ Até pode funcionar, mas vai ser dificil garantir que tudo fica "onde você quer"

Comment: @Sergio muito obrigado pela luz. Eu tive a ideia de mexer por `position:absolute` e ficou assim: http://jsfiddle.net/andretf/e54eZ/! Pode postar como uma resposta para eu poder dar a pergunta como resolvida?

Comment: @Sergio Corrigindo o link do comentário anterior: http://jsfiddle.net/andretf/e54eZ/3/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Caso você não tenha problemas com browsers antigos, você pode utilizar [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Supondo que você tenha um elemento pai destes três outros blocos, ficaria assim:

```
.elemento-pai {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d2 {
  order: 3;
}

.d3 {
  order: 2;
}
```

Desta forma trocando os elementos de posição e preservando a dinâmica deles (um continua empurrando o outro pra baixo, etc).

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/L4jmhuk9/)**

Comment: Ótimo exemplo. CSS esta se tornando um canivete suíço.

Comment: Boa resposta, mas o css ainda não funciona em todos os navegadores (IE8, IE9..).

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo pois é, é uma feature relativamente nova (CSS3), por isso destaquei na primeira frase que só deve ser usado caso navegadores antigos não sejam problema.

Comment: Atualizei pra ter esta resposta como a aceita, já que hoje em 2016 ela é [amplamente aceita](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) pelos navegadores atuais.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode forçar os elementos a posicionarem-se onde quer. Se tomar este caminho o melhor é que todos os elementos estejam posicionados, e que tenha controlo sobre as suas dimensões para não cruzarem uns por cima dos outros.

Aqui fica uma sugestão: http://jsfiddle.net/e54eZ/1/

```
.d1, .d3 {
    color: #cc9900;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute; # para os poder mover livremente

}
.d2 {
    margin-top: 20px; # para deixar espaço para os outros elementos
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
/* PArte nova */
.d3 {
    top: 5px;
    left: 120px;
}
.d1 {
    top: 5px;
    left: 7px;
}
```