# Permutar a posicao de divs HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Como mostra a imagem. Tenho uma `div` mae contendo 5 `div` alinhados verticalmente.

Como faço pra mudar a posicao da ultima div `contact` posicionando-a entre `home` e `services` sem ter que mudar a estrura HTML ( simplesmente usando CSS ou JS).

Tentei usar `position: relative` e `position: absolute` e mover a `div` com proprieades `top`. O problema é que ao mover o elemento ele fica sobreposto aos outros (por cima).

Qual seria a solucao pra esse caso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que exatamente precisa ser em CSS?. O ideal seria alterar o HTML ou dinamicamente com JavaScript.

Comment: @mauhumor alterei a questao... Uma solucao com Js também é valida !

Comment: Explique melhor o contexto, e acrescente o HTML do trecho relevante, que fica mais fácil.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Tem como alterar a ordem vertical de divs por CSS?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20927/tem-como-alterar-a-ordem-vertical-de-divs-por-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20927) citada como duplicada não permite uma solução com JavaScript, colocarei aqui uma simples utilizando jQuery.

Considerando a estrutura HTML a seguir:

```
<div id="menu">
  <div>Home</div>
  <div>Services</div>
  <div>Products</div>
  <div>Our puppies</div>
  <div>Contact</div>
</div>
```

Podemos utilizar o seguinte código com jQuery para reposicionar a última `div`, colocando-a na segunda posição.

```
$(function () {
  var contact = $("#menu div:last-child");
  var home = $("#menu div:first-child");

  home.after(contact);
});
```

Veja este exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/F4BR/0).